# Unable to delete empty object properties with javascript and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular 1.6.

I need remove some properties of a javascript object if they are null, empty or undefined.

In my case,  i have two empty arrays 'byweekday" and "bymonth" and I am 
trying to  delete them from object, without success.

What am I doing wrong?

//markup

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" type="button" 
                     ng-click="makecalc()">
                     Calculate
</button>
```

//code

//angular controller

```
     $scope.repeticao={"wkst":1,"freq":{"id":0,"name":"Anualmente"},"byweekday":
   [],"bymonth":[]};

    function removeEmpty(obj) {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') removeEmpty(obj[key])
        else if (obj[key] === null || obj[key] === undefined) delete obj[key]
      });
      return obj;
    };
    $scope.makecalc=function(){
          //debugger;
          var key, value, date;
          var values = angular.copy($scope.repeticao);
          values=removeEmpty(values);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(values)); 
    }
```

Comment: Your code only deletes a key when the value is `null` or `undefined` not an empty array.

Comment: Why don't you create a brand new object inside the removeEmpty() function and assign properties in for loop, then return it?

Comment: Hi, I also tried: if (values.byweekday.length=0) delete  values.byweekday; but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only deletes a key when the value is `null` or `undefined` so, obviously, it won't delete an empty array, so you'll need to check for that as well. Since `typeof` is also `"object"` you'll need to check for a removable-item first. (Also, using `==` with null checks for both `null` and `undefined`, so we can simplify that as well):

```
function removeEmpty(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (obj[key] == null || (Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].length === 0)) {
      delete obj[key];
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      removeEmpty(obj[key]);
    }
  });
  return obj;
};
```

Comment: Hi, It doesn't work. The array  is not  been removed

Comment: @LuizAlves You're right. It's the typeof check, since an array's typeof is "object" you'll need to check for an empty array first. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Now it´s working. But why the code: " if (values.byweekday.length=0) delete values.byweekday;" doesn´t works?

Comment: Than you, Mr rgthree